# Decrypting a Message Encrypted in RSA Using Two Coprime Encryption Keys

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

The last question of our number theory final review is as follows:

> The same plaintext $P$ is encrypted in RSA using two coprime encryption keys $e_1$, $e_2$. Show how this message can be decrypted quickly if both ciphertexts $C_1$, $C_2$ are intercepted.
>
> **Hint:** Bézout's identity.

I know the RSA cryptosystem has it that

$$\begin{align}
C_1&\equiv P^{e_1}\pmod{n_1}\text{ and}\\
C_2&\equiv P^{e_2}\pmod{n_2},
\end{align}$$

where $n_1=p_1q_1$, $n_2=p_2q_2$, $(e_1,\varphi(n_1))=1$, and $(e_2,\varphi(n_2))=1$, for some large primes $p_1$, $q_1$, $p_2$, and $q_2$.

Since one does not have access to the secret keys $d_1$ and $d_2$, I assume Bézout's identity must play a big role here. However, the only place I can think of using it is with the encryption keys

$$\begin{align}
1&=e_1s_1+n_1t_1,\\
1&=e_2s_2+n_2t_2,\text{ and}\\
1&=e_1s_3+e_2t_3,
\end{align}$$

for some integers $s_1$, $t_1$, $s_2$, $t_2$, $s_3$, and $t_3$.

Nevertheless, this is not very useful. What am I missing?

Comment: Use the third one, relating $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Comment: I suppose then that one can find the plaintext $P$ by multiplying $C_1$ by $(e_2t_3)/s_3$? Is it that simple?

Comment: Are you sure that two different moduli $n_1$ and $n_2$ are used?  Perhaps you just have a single $n=pq$ used in both encryptions, so that $C_1 \equiv P^{e_1} \pmod{n}$ and $C_2 \equiv P^{e_2} \pmod{n}$.

Comment: @JonasKibelbek, the question doesn't specify that, but you could be right, and forgive my ignorance, but what difference would different moduli make?

Comment: @JosuéMolina: Well, I don't see a way to recover $P$ if the encryptions use different moduli (I suspect there is no easy way); but if the moduli are the same, Bézout's identity does give you an easy way.  Your earlier idea of multiplying $C_1$ by $(e_2t_3)/s_3$ will not work.  You need to work with the exponents to recover $P$.

Comment: @JosuéMolina: The solution actually does not require taking roots modulo $n$.  When you write $C_2^{t/s}$, it looks like you are asking for an $s$-th root modulo $n$.  This is a problem, because if $(s,\varphi(n))\neq 1$, then not every residue class has a unique $s$-th root.  Every residue class *does* have a unique $e_2$-th root, but finding it is *very* difficult in general-- this is the strength of RSA encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the messages $C_1$ and $C_2$ were encrypted with the *same* modulus $n=pq$, even though different exponents $e_1$ and $e_2$ were used.  Then we have 
$$C_1 \equiv P^{e_1} \pmod{n}$$
$$C_2 \equiv P^{e_2} \pmod{n}.$$
Further, we can find integers $s$ and $t$ such that $se_1+te_2 =1$.

Can you figure out how to obtain $P^{se_1+te_2} \pmod{n}$?  Can you see why this idea works if the same modulus $n$ is used for both encryptions, but does not work if we have two different moduli $n_1$ and $n_2$?

Comment: I ended up with $P\equiv C_1^s\cdot C_2^t$.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  One of the integers $s$ and $t$ will be negative.  So to calculate $P$, you will need to find an inverse of $C_1$ or of $C_2$ modulo $n$, do modular exponentiation, and multiply two numbers modulo $n$.  All of these steps are very fast, so you have found an easy way to calculate $P$.